# Python max with same number of instances

Tags: python, max, instances

I have a list:

```
hello = ['1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '2', '7']
```

I wanted to display the most common element of the list, so I used:

```
m = max(set(hello), key=hello.count)
```

However, I realised that there could be two elements of the list that occur the same frequency, like the 1's and 2's in the list above.  Max only outputs the first instance of a maximum frequency element.

What kind of command could check a list to see if two elements both have the maximum number of instances, and if so, output them both?  I am at a loss here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using an approach similar to your current, you would first find the maximum count and then look for every item with that count:

```
>>> m = max(map(hello.count, hello))
>>> set(x for x in hello if hello.count(x) == m)
set(['1', '2'])
```

Alternatively, you can use the nice [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class, which can be used to efficiently, well, count stuff:

```
>>> hello = ['1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '2', '7']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(hello)
>>> c
Counter({'1': 3, '2': 3, '7': 1})
>>> common = c.most_common()
>>> common
[('1', 3), ('2', 3), ('7', 1)]
```

Then you can use a list comprehension to get all the items that have the maximum count:

```
>>> set(x for x, count in common if count == common[0][1])
set(['1', '2'])
```

Comment: What about times when there are 3 repeated numbers, like ['1', '1', '2', '2', '8', '7', '7']... your script won't work for that.  Thanks, otherwise the solution is good.

Comment: @james: Can't reproduce, it returns `set(['1', '2', '7'])` for me with both code snippets.

Comment: Ah yes, no problem, it's working great for me now.  Many thanks.

Comment: The second line of your first solution could be shortened too.
`{x for x in hello if hello.count(x) == m}`

Comment: @jam: Yes, right, I usually don't use set comprehensions, for some reason. But then again I like dict comprehensions really much... For this post, I'll keep it as it is, because this way it also works in 2.6 (which is still the default in some Linux distros...).

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Changed solution

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> hello = ['1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '2', '7']
>>> max_count, max_nums = next(groupby(Counter(hello).most_common(),
                               lambda x: x[1]))
>>> print [num for num, count in max_nums]
['1', '2']
```

Comment: +1, nice and clean solution. The last line could be marginally simplified to `d[max(d)]` :)

Comment: Thanks, now it looks even nicer :D

Comment: The problem with this method is it's O(n**2). `sequence.count` is O(n) and you do it once for each item in the sequence. The `Counter` method, or a hand-coded equivalent, is O(n) -- the number of operations per item is independent of the number of items in the sequence.

Comment: Noted. I understand that `Counter` is more well suited to these operations, just thought this method looks very clean :)

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

def myFunction(myDict):
    myMax = 0 # Keep track of the max frequence
    myResult = [] # A list for return

    for key in myDict:
        print('The key is', key, ', The count is', myDict[key])
        print('My max is:', myMax)
        # Finding out the max frequence
        if myDict[key] >= myMax:
            if myDict[key] == myMax:
                myMax = myDict[key]
                myResult.append(key)
            # Case when it is greater than, we will delete and append
            else:
                myMax = myDict[key]
                del myResult[:]
                myResult.append(key)
    return myResult

foo = ['1', '1', '5', '2', '1', '6', '7', '10', '2', '2']
myCount = Counter(foo)
print(myCount)

print(myFunction(myCount))
```

Output:

```
The list: ['1', '1', '5', '2', '1', '6', '7', '10', '2', '2']
Counter({'1': 3, '2': 3, '10': 1, '5': 1, '7': 1, '6': 1})
The key is 10 , The count is 1
My max is: 0
The key is 1 , The count is 3
My max is: 1
The key is 2 , The count is 3
My max is: 3
The key is 5 , The count is 1
My max is: 3
The key is 7 , The count is 1
My max is: 3
The key is 6 , The count is 1
My max is: 3
['1', '2']
```

I wrote this simple program, I think it might also work. I was not aware of the `most_common()` function until I do a search. I think this will return as many most frequent element there is, it works by comparing the max frequent element, when I see a more frequent element, it will delete the result list, and append it once; or if it is the same frequency, it simply append to it. And keep going until the whole Counter is iterated through.

Comment: This is a great example! It shows how to do this yourself if you're not just looking for the easiest way.

Comment: I learned something too, I learned how the `most_common()` function work, and bookmarked it in case in the future I need that particular function again. So it is win-win for all of us, cheers!